# Missing autocomplete and documentation

Tags: xcode, xcode8-beta4

I downloaded the Xcode8 Beta.

There is only autocomplete based on other text in the same file, but not anything related to class methods, etc.

Also I don't have any documentation of Swift and if I go to "Settings"->"Components"->"Documentation", I can only find 'Guides and Sample Code'.

Is there any way to get these features in the beta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at "Xcode - Window - Documentation and API References" (or Shift + CMD + 0). There you should see Swift, Objective-C as well as JavaScript documentations. 
To check for beta documentations you can search for new services introduced with iOS 10. 
If the documentation exists and you still don't get any autocompletion in Xcode this may be a bug in Xcode beta und you should report it to Apple.